Has any information survived about OS BAMOS for BESM-6, written in DDR?
Recently I learned that there was an operating system for the BESM-6 mainframe developed in DDR: a bibliographical list includes

and quite a few more German-language publications (up to item 105), pages 14-16 of the linked PDF.
Searching for "OS BAMOS" online returns nothing of relevance, as could be expected.
I'm interested in reading at least a brief description of that operating system. The hope that any source code or binary has survived is dim, but at least some of these descriptive publications should still be held somewhere in paper form. Is there a way to obtain scans/OCRs/translations of those?
Perhaps Dieter Carl or Dieter Hammer, the authors of Funktionen und Struktur von Betriebssystemen für Großrechenanlagen mit Multiprogramming und Einordnung des Betriebssystems BAMOS für die Großrechenanlage BESM 6 ("Functions and structure of operating systems for mainframe computers with multiprogramming and classification of the BAMOS operating system for the BESM 6 mainframe computer") could be found?

Three items in German libraries apparently https://portal.dnb.de/opac/simpleSearch?query=besm-6+bamos

2nd could be here https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/241308946/dieter-hammer
